# code to download gpx route from googlemaps route

Tags: google-maps, export, gpx

I managed to do a routeplanner with Googlemaps but I wanted people to download their route.

I have put the following code in a download.php file, but something is wrong as when I test it the file is blank.

Anyone know what is wrong?

Is the route it creates called something else?
I am not sure it is knowing the route name to download, I made up the Myroute.gpx??

The code I am using is:-

```
<? ob_start(); ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body><?php

//download.php
//content type header('Content-type: Application/octet-stream');
//open/save dialog box
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="MyRoute.gpx"');
//read from server and write to buffer
readfile('text.txt');

?>
</body>
</html><? ob_flush(); ?>
```

thanks

Comment: how do you save the route in `text.txt`? Are you sure that the file is writeable?

Comment: Hi, I am new at all this sorry. Took me ages to get as far as I have - Do I have the change text.txt to text.gpx - also how do I know that is the name of the file google creates for the route? How can I check? thanks Shirl

Comment: You must change `text.txt` to the path of the file where you've stored the data(of course this file must be readable).

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go and let you know.

Comment: Also note: you must remove anything that produces an output except the `readfile()`-call ....otherwise the gpx will be invalid.

Comment: The text.txt is blank still, am I to remove anything else?

In the HTML file I have

<form id="formExportData" method="post" action="Download.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:none">
<textArea id="exportData" name="exportData"></textArea>
</form>

<input name="file" id="file" type="file" style="display:none" />

Comment: Download.php is
<? ob_start(); ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body><?php

//download.php
//content type header('Content-type: Application/octet-stream');
//open/save dialog box
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="MyRoute.gpx"');
//read from server and write to buffer
readfile('full url/text.txt');

?>
</body>
</html><? ob_flush(); ?>

Comment: I checked the text.txt i changed to writeable. Have I removed all the output files you said? Sorry for the few comments would only allow certain amount a box.

Shirl

Comment: When I open the gpx file in notepad to see whats in it it only has <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body></body>
</html>

Comment: the text.txt obviously is empty or not readable(maybe the path is wrong)

Comment: How do you point the google maps route to write it on the text.txt file do you now? I can only think its not writing the route on the file. Its the right path and its writeable, I cant think of anything else it could be.